# How to check if a value of array exists in other group of arrays

Tags: php, php-8

I have an array contains the dates of last 7 days, this array is created with o loop.

```
    $now = new \DateTime();
    $startDate = $now->modify('-6 day');
    $labels = [];
    $data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        $day =  $startDate->modify('+1 day');
        $labels[] = $day->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

and this is the output of $labels:

```
$labels = array:7 [▼
  0 => "2023-07-05"
  1 => "2023-07-06"
  2 => "2023-07-07"
  3 => "2023-07-08"
  4 => "2023-07-09"
  5 => "2023-07-10"
  6 => "2023-07-11"
]
```

And I have a query to select number of views of an element (Property) in this dates.
This query can return 7 rows as it can return less than 7 or also 0 rows if there is not views in any of days.
In my case , I have visits only in the last two days and this is the output of result:

```
$result = array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▶
    "numberViews" => 20
    "dayDate" => "2023-07-10"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▶
    "numberViews" => 32
    "dayDate" => "2023-07-11"
  ]
]
```

**What I'd like to do** is to check each date in the first array if exists in the group of arrays returned by the query, if it doesn't exist so it should be zero **and make an array of data like so**:

```
$data = [0,0,0,0,0,20,32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to initialize your $data array to have the same array-keys as your $labels array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $day =  $startDate->modify('+1 day');
    $labels[] = $day->format('Y-m-d');
    $data[] = 0;
}
```

Now you can iterate your $result array and use the php function array_search to count the number of views.

```
foreach($result as $item)
{
    $foundKey = array_search($item['dayDate'], $labels);
    if($foundKey !== false)
    {
        $data[$foundKey] += $item['numberViews'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two simple steps:

1. create an array that has the labels as indices and 0 as values;
2. run through `$result` and replace `0` with the number of views, for the dates present in `$result`.

```php
$labels = [
  0 => "2023-07-05",
  1 => "2023-07-06",
  2 => "2023-07-07",
  3 => "2023-07-08",
  4 => "2023-07-09",
  5 => "2023-07-10",
  6 => "2023-07-11",
];

$result = [
  0 => [
    "numberViews" => 20,
    "dayDate" => "2023-07-10",
  ],
  1 => [
    "numberViews" => 32,
    "dayDate" => "2023-07-11",
  ],
];

// 1. create the output array; set the dates/labels as keys and 0 as values
$output = array_fill_keys($labels, 0);
// 2. fill the number of views for the dated that have views
foreach ($result as $day) {
  // Modify only the values that exist in $output
  if (isset($output[$day['dayDate']])) {
    // Use addition instead of assignment to guard for duplicate dates in $result
    $output[$day['dayDate']] += $day['numberViews'];
  }
}

print_r($output);
```

You can combine step #1 into your existing code, to generate `$output` instead of `$labels` (and you don't need step #1 above any more):

```php
    $now = new \DateTime();
    $startDate = $now->modify('-6 day');
    $output = [];
    $data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        $day =  $startDate->modify('+1 day');
        $output[$day->format('Y-m-d')] = 0;
    }
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/Ajspl).

Comment: This answer will not work proper. Assuming i.e. you have dayDate "2023-06-01" in your $result array, this will also be added to the $output array. Further you will have wrong number of views, if there would be two entries in your $result array with same dayDate.

Comment: I agree with the first flaw, but why would `$result` contain multiple entries with the same `dayDate`?

Comment: I don't know. :-) Should not. But the function to create the $result array is unknown. And due to the askers skills it could happen.